# Stability of Explicit midpoint method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, runge-kutta-methods

I am trying to determine the stability region of the well known explicit midpoint method
$$y_{i+1} = y_i + h f\left( t_i + \frac h 2, \ y_i + \frac h 2 f(t_i, y_i)\right)$$ and after following the links [Determine a stability region?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1975043) and [Calculating stability and order of implicit midpoint scheme](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2270787), I managed to apply the numerical method on the test equation and got
$$\begin{align*}y_{i+1} & = y_i + h f\left( t_i + \frac h 2, \ y_i + \frac h 2 f(t_i, y_i)\right) \\ & = 
 y_i + \left( \lambda h +\frac{\lambda^2h^2}{2}  \right)y_i \\ 
& = \left( 1 + \lambda h +\frac{\lambda^2h^2}{2}  \right)y_i\end{align*}$$
Stability: $\big| 1 + \lambda h +\frac{\lambda^2h^2}{2}\big|<1$ and simplifying, $-2 < (1+ \lambda h)^2<0$ is the stability. I don't know if the stability region is correct. How do I find it?

Comment: Please check the method and its name, in the text you use the explicit midpoint method. In the calculation you missed to set parentheses leading to a wrong result. $$=y_i+h·λ\left(y_i+\frac h2·λy_i\right)$$

Comment: It was a typo the title of the question should be contain explicit not implicit. I have edited it a such. So with the explicit midpoint, is my computation right? and how do I find the stability region?

Comment: No, your computation is not right, you should get the second degree Taylor polynomial of $\exp(hλ)$, like for any explicit 2-stage second-order method.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I made a couple of changes for your reference.

Comment: Yes, that is now correct. But you also need to take complex eigenvalues $λ$ into consideration. I'm not sure if there is a "nice" solution to this. $z^2+2z+2=2e^{i\phi}$ can be solved as quadratic equation, but is there a nice geometric interpretation of the solution formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some way, you already found the region of absolute stability, which is in this case $$\left \vert 1 + z + 0.5z^2 \right \vert \leq 1, \quad z = \Delta t \lambda.$$

If you want to know e.g. the boundary of the absolute region of stability, you need to get your hands dirty and split $z$ in real and imaginary part $z = a + bi$ and perform many operations or ask [Wolfram Alpha for help](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=simplify%20%7C%201%20%2B%20a%20%2B%20b*i%20%2B%200.5%20*%20%28a%20%2B%20b*i%29%5E2%20%7C) which computes for real $a, b$

$$\sqrt{\Big(0.5 \big(a^2 - b^2\big) + a + 1\Big)^2 + \big(a b + b\big)^2} \leq 1 $$

and then [solve for](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve%20for%20sqrt%28%280.5%20%28a%5E2%20-%20b%5E2%29%20%2B%20a%20%2B%201%29%5E2%20%2B%20%28a%20b%20%2B%20b%29%5E2%29%20%3D%201%20for%20b) $b$ as a function of $a$ the boundary $$\sqrt{\Big(0.5 \big(a^2 - b^2\big) + a + 1\Big)^2 + \big(a b + b\big)^2} = 1 $$

which gives two candidates

$$ b = \pm \sqrt{-a^2 - 2 a \color{red}- 2 \sqrt{-a (a + 2)}} $$
$$ b = \pm \sqrt{-a^2 - 2 a \color{red}+ 2 \sqrt{-a (a + 2)}} $$

Based on your knowledge that for real $\lambda$ you have that $-2 \leq z^2 \leq 0$ you could then figure out that only the second possibility gives real solutions for $b$.
Or, you just plot both and see what gives a real solution.
Since there are only two solutions for the second and third quadrant, respectively, it is guaranteed that there are no holes within that region.
Indeed,

[image]