# Butcher table to $y_{n+1}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, implicit-differentiation

I am trying to understand how to go from a [Butcher table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#Implicit_Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) to something useful of the form $y_{n+1} = g(y_n, y_{n+1})$.

Let us  first try the simplest case, which is backwards Euler.

Using the coefficients from [the table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#Implicit_methods) we would get:

$$k_1 = f(t +h, y_n + hk_1)$$
$$y_{n+1} = y_n + hk_1$$

In this setting we can do

$$y_{n+1} - y_n = hk_1 \iff k_1 = \frac{y_{n+1} - y_n}{h}$$

Replacing into the first equation yould yield:

$$k_1 = f(t+h, y_n + (y_{n+1} - y_n)) = f(t+h, y_{n+1})$$

And now into the second we get:

$$y_{n+1} = y_n + hf(t+h, y_{n+1})$$

How about in the more general setting? How do you replace each $k_i$ by some expersion of $y_{n+1}$? I am trying to come up with a good systematic way but the math is getting convoluted. Say, for example, we wanted to do third order RADUA IIA which has this table:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no difference if the implicit equation is in $k_1$ or in $y_{n+1}$. And your observation is correct, with more than one stage you can not express the $k_1,k_2,...,k_s$ in $y_{n+1}$, but you can define the intermediate points
$$y_{n,i}=y_n+h\sum_ja_{ij}k_j,~~k_i=f(t_n+c_ih,y_{n,i}),$$ and eliminate the slopes $k_i$ from the stages. I'm not aware of any numerical advantages of this substitution.

Comment: I see. The reason why I wanted to express everything in terms of $y_{n+1}$ is because I want to find the stability region.

Based on this answer to prior question:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1975043/determine-a-stability-region

I thought if I had an expression of the form $y_{n+1} = Ky_n$ where the left term is fully isolated I could similarly find the stability region by bounding the coefficient. 

If it is not possible to express things in just $y_{n+1}$ then I am not sure how to fidn teh stability region.

Comment: If you apply the Runge-Kutta method to a linear system $y'=Ay$ or the scalar linear test DE $y'=\lambda y$, then the implicit system for the stages can actually be solved, and you get $y_{n+1}=R(hA)y_n$ or $y_{n+1}=R(\lambda h)y_n$ where $R(z)$ is a rational function, a quotient of polynomial. Then indeed you can test for which $z$ with $Re(z)\le 0$ you get $|R(z)|\le 1$ or how bad the difference from $e^z$ is to $R(z)$.